# Sum of uniform and exponential random variables

Tags: probability, integration, statistics

$$U \sim \operatorname{unif}(0,1);X \sim \operatorname{expo}(1) .$$
$U,X$ indep.

Find the PDF of $U+X$.

Here's my answer, but I find this answer implausible, not sure where I went wrong.

---

\begin{align}
F_Y(y) & =P(U+X \leq y) \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P(U+X < y \mid X=x)f_X(x)\,dx \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P(U < y - X\mid X=x)f_X(x)\,dx \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P(U < y - x\mid X=x)f_X(x)\,dx \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P(U < y - x)f_X(x)\,dx \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F_U(y-x)f_X(x)\,dx \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (y-x)f_X(x)\,dx \\
&= \operatorname E_X[y-X] \\ 
&= y - \operatorname E_X[X] \\
&= y - 1/\lambda \\
&= y - 1/1 \\
&= y - 1
\end{align}

$$
f_Y(y) = \frac d {dy} F_Y(y) = 1
$$

Comment: You seem to have two instances of two identical lines adjacent to each other in this string of equalities.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $F_U(y-x)=\begin{cases} 0 & , y-x < 0\\y-x & ,y-x \in [0,1] \\
1 &, y-x > 1\end{cases}$.

Comment: Isn't $F_U (y-x) = 1$ when $y-x>1$?

Comment: you are right, i miss that.